# Sawtooth - configure-onchain-perms problem -

Tags: hyperledger, blockchain, hyperledger-sawtooth

I want to do some specific task using sawtooth in combination with ansible. I am using this ansible project https://github.com/hyperledger/sawtooth-ansible. The problem is when I want to run "Configure onchain permissions". The main problem is in **configure-onchain-perms** role in task **Create Transaction Access Policy**. Always as a result, I get the time out. Also, I tried to install everything manually, without ansible, but output is the same. The same result is with this simple command **sawtooth identity policy create policy_1 "PERMIT_KEY *"**. Could anyone guide me how to use identity family in right way ?

Answer (score 0):

Is the identity transaction processor, `identity-tp` running on all nodes?

A quote from:
https://sawtooth.hyperledger.org/docs/core/releases/latest/cli/identity-tp.html

> This process is required to apply any changes to on-chain permissions
>   used by the Sawtooth platform.

There is also an active chat forum for Sawtooth at https://chat.hyperledger.org/channel/sawtooth